# How to generate a series of pulses whose ON time follows the binomial distribution?

Tags: algorithm, binomial-cdf

I have a simple question:

I am trying to simulate a train of digital pulses (max=1, min=0). The distribution of ON-times should follow a Binomial distribution. How do I do this? I am using VisualStudio 2012. This is a very trivial question and I don't mean to waste anybody's time, but for some reason my mind is not working when I think about this problem. I need to generate a very large dataset (300Mb).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the native RNG of visual studio generates integers between 0 to M-1, calculate K = p*M. Generate as many random numbers you like and threshold them at K to get your binary random pulses.

Other way would be:

For each possible byte (whole 256 of them) count the number of 1s. Create two sets (possibly of unequal size) of bytes A and B such that p = 0.5*ProbabilityofOne(A) + 0.5*ProbabilityofOne(B). Now at every moment randomly choose a set (A or B) and then choose an element from the set randomly. This way you get 8 pulses for every random number generated.

NOTE: p is the expected probability of 1s.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to parse what you said. (Noob here).

Comment: @AntillarMaximus I have been fuzzy on the second part. Feel free to ask for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to generate numbers that follow a [binomial distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982497%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I edited Microsoft's example and tried to give variables better naming and make it easier to read altogether.

My grasp on probability and statistics is waning since it's been so long since I used it, so I hope this is correct...

```
#include <random> //include the random number library
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    mt19937 rng; //create an instance of the Mersenne Twister PRNG
    binomial_distribution<int, double> binomDistribution(2, 0.6); //create distribution using t=2 and p= 0.6
    auto randomNumber = rng(); //get a random number from the RNG
    auto binDistValue = binomDistribution(rng); //get a binomial distributed number from the RNG

    std::cout << "p == " << binomDistribution.p() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "t == " << binomDistribution.t() << std::endl; 

    binomDistribution.reset(); // discard any cached values 

    const auto valuesToPrint = 100;
    cout << "First " << valuesToPrint << " values of the binomial distribution are:" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<valuesToPrint; ++i)
    {
        auto aSampledValue = binomDistribution(rng);
        cout << aSampledValue << endl;
    }    

    return (0); 
}
```

Also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163305/c11-stls-binomial-distribution-extremely-slow) to see possibly an even simpler example.

The key points are:

- pick an RNG
- define your distribution
- give the RNG to your distribution so it can generate a single result for you

Comment: Thank you. I am using C++. Is there detailed documentation on the class file you use? Microsoft's documentation is not noob friendly.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus Can you clarify? Are you a statistics noob, a C++ noob, or some other flavor of noob? Personally, I'm a statistics noob, since it's been so long since I used prob and stats. I will edit some comments into the Microsoft example.