# std::binomial_distribution hangs forever with certain inputs

Tags: c++, random

I have encountered some odd behavior with `std::binomial_distribution` when compiling with `clang++` (with `libstdc++` standard library).

Consider the following simple program:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

unsigned binom(unsigned n, double p) {
  std::mt19937 e(time(NULL));
  std::binomial_distribution<unsigned> b(n, p);
  return b(e);
}

int main() {

  std::cout << "sample1=" << binom(1073741823, 0.51174692866744709) << "\n";
  std::cout << "sample2=" << binom(1073741824, 0.51174692866744709) << "\n";

}
```

This program will output one line (`sample1=511766586\n`) and then hang indefinitely.

Have I somehow invoked undefined behavior? This appears to happen regardless of what the PRNG returns. No matter how I seed it my `main` hangs on this second line.

Comment: BTW, you DON'T want to reinitialize the mersenne twister every time: https://godbolt.org/z/devvx3hPz

Comment: Unrelated: Avoid using time as the seed for anything important. Anyone who knows when the program started can predict the outputs. The standard recommendation is to use a [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device). Hmmm someone seems to have screwed up or vandalized the doc page and renamed it to std::promise. Content looks correct, though.

Comment: Thank you both for your concern, but yes I would never do either of these in practice!

Comment: Here a [mre]: https://godbolt.org/z/vvq7T6WxP

Comment: I can reproduce with GCC 12.2. Infinite rejection loop in `binomial_distribution::operator()`. Lacking a MSVC at the moment to complete the sweep of the big three. I'm going to have to leave this to someone who actually knows how this smurf works.

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you for posting the mre. Definitely seems to be an issue within libstdc++.

Comment: @user4581301 Unrelated, but what is an MSVC?

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163305/c11-stls-binomial-distribution-extremely-slow . Also, MSVC stands for Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Apologies for using an out of date acronym. **M**icro**S**oft **V**isual **C**.

Comment: Bob__ raises a good point. I didn't let the loop run long enough to prove it really was infinite.

Comment: @Bob__ I noticed that if you sample from a binomial distribution for `n+10, n+9, n+8, ..., n+1`, that the execution time does increase significantly at each step. However, I've been running this program on a node in our HPC facility for quite a while now. Well over 15 minutes at this point, which far exceeds any of the other execution times.

Comment: The normal distribution with `mean = n * p` and `sigma = sqrt(n * p * (1-p))` is considered a very good approximation of the binomial when both `n * p > 10` and `n * (1-p) > 10`. Your `n` is so gigantic that you’re massively over those limits. Generating a normal with the specified parameters and rounding will be extremely fast and indistinguishable from the binomial, plus you won’t have to wait for the bug noted below to be fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I debugged the GCC implementation of `binomial_distribution` ([`_M_initialize`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/0846336de56119777861e02bf68f92a6af466000/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.tcc#L1473), [`operator()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/0846336de56119777861e02bf68f92a6af466000/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.tcc#L1560)), and this is what I found:

Because of an overflow of the unsigned parameter `n` (2^30)
the variable `_M_s2` of the `__param` object becomes `inf`
and therefore the same happens to `__s2s`, `_M_s` of the same object and `__u`, `__a12`, `__y` in `operator()`

This leads to the following infinite loop in `operator()`

```
bool __reject;
do
{
    if (__u <= __a1)                        inf <= val --> false
    {
        [...]
    }
    else if (__u <= __a12)                  inf <= inf --> true
    {
        __reject = __y >= [...];            inf >= val --> true
    }
    __reject = __reject || [...];           true || bool --> true
    __reject |= [...];                      true | val --> truthy
}
while(__reject);
```

Here is a (partial) traceback of how those variables got to equal `inf`:

```
_M_t = n

_M_s2 = [...] * (1 + [double] / (4 * _M_t * [...]));
                                 ^^^^^^^^ overflow == 0
                     [double] / 0 == inf

__s2s = _M_s2 * _Ms2;

_M_s = [...] + __s2s * [...];


__u = __param._M_s * [...];

__a12 = [...] + __param._M_s2 * [...];

__y = __param._M_s2 * [...];
```

Is also worth noting that `__d2x` in the `__param` object is `NaN` and that the other variables that contribute to this process, of which I omitted the definition, have (at least in this context) valid values

A feasible solution (until the bug is fixed) would be using `std::binomial_distribution<unsigned long>` (or `uint64_t`) in place of `unsigned`

---

Update: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114359

Comment: Wow, nice work! How did you go about debugging this?

Comment: @FloydEverest thank you! It wasn't easy... The first helpful thing I found was actually `__d2x` being NaN, then I noticed a `32 * _M_t`  on the line it was defined. From there I found the `_M_s2` and traced everything down

Comment: size_t instead of unsigned long? unsigned long is 32bit on windows

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Yes, you're right, even better would be `uint64_t`

Comment: I had a similar experience - the GCC boys were very reactive on fixing overflows in the STL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73157920/undefined-behavior-according-to-clang-fsanitize-integer-on-libstdc-stdran
Although there was a clear underflow in the code, they said the bug was in the C++ standard, not in libstdc++.

Comment: "until the bug is fixed": did someone make a report on gcc's bugzilla?

Comment: No, it has not been reported. So I can't imagine why it hasn't been fixed ...